# Auto-correlation of each column of a matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab

My data is included in a matrix (dim: 900 x 10) called input_data_matrix, each column of this matrix has 900 time-series random signals (light readings integer values).
I want to compute the relation (or correlation) between these 900 readings of same column independently, (not correlation with the other columns readings), such that I can get 10 correlation result values corresponding to the 10 column which are indicate how much the 900 readings of each column are correlate,
So, my question is how I can compute this in matlab and what is the best type of correlation to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, what you want is the autocorrelation of each column of your input data. In that case, I would use the `xcorr` function (https://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html), which for a given vector computes its autocorrelation. The code would be the following:

```
[m, n] = size(input_data_matrix);
output_matrix = zeros(m, n);

for i = 1:n
  output_matrix(:,i) = xcorr(input_data_matrix(:,i));
end
```

Comment: I have checked (xcorr) before, I think it used to find the correlation between the combination of columns not between items of the the same column.
r = xcorr(x,y) returns the cross-correlation of two discrete-time sequences, x and y.

Comment: If you look at the next line of the MathWorks doc you'll see that says: " r = xcorr(x) returns the autocorrelation sequence of x", which is what you are looking for. I'll suggest you to try my code, it works.